# React Native Gifted Chat showing invalid date in android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, chat, react-native-gifted-chat

React Native Gifted Chat showing invalidate date in Android phone.
if I show one day of date message it works fine but if I show multiple days of date like (1 September, 2 September etc) messages it is showing invalid date

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5KiH.jpg): [see the attached image] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5KiH.jpg)https://i.stack.imgur.com/1imYf.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a [mcve] so others can understand your situation and give advice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.